# Missing write access when installing dojo/cli (trying to avoid sudo)

Tags: javascript, dojo, fedora, dojo2

I'm following the "Get Going Quickly" from dojo.io and I've entered

```
npm i @dojo/cli @dojo/cli-create-app -g
```

but it fails with

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
```

How can avoid this without using `sudo`? I’ve heard I should never use `sudo` with `npm`.
Is it correct? Should I really avoid it also in this case?
I'm on **Fedora version 32** and

```
npm -v
6.14.4
```

I've also tried to issue only

```
npm i @dojo/cli -g
```

according to the Readme of [dojo/cli](https://github.com/dojo/cli) but the error is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set your current user as owner of this node module folder as follow ( $USER refers to your current user name )

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Comment: @Giulio , agreed , not only those , all modern framework use a bunch of data for a small project ,